# Falha no deploy de arquivo python no Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, deploy, heroku

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer o deploy de um arquivo python **3.7.1** no Heroku porém na documentação do heroku informa que suporta a versão **3.7.2**.
Segue erro abaixo:
Erro: Requested runtime (Python 3.7.1) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atualmente o Heroku suporta **apenas** as versões 2.7.17, 3.7.2 e 3.6.8 do Python, sendo a última, 3.6.8, definida por padrão e você só pode utilizar estas versões.

Você pode encontrar maiores detalhes na [documentação sobre o suporte a Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) dentro do Heroku.